# i want to include my flight.php file in flights.php file

Tags: php

I have a flights.php file contains html code.

I have a flight.php file contains php code.

i want to include flight.php into flights.php and i want to use one global variable of flight.php in flights.php.

can any body help me to do this.

Comment: include_once("flight.php");

Answer (score 0):

If you require the file inside flights.php like:

```
require_once 'flight.php';
```

You'll get the content of the file added to your flights.php and variables will be available too.

Comment: i want to use flight.php variable in flights.php javascript.

Comment: Will be hard to help if you don't show the code you have.
All you are saying is that you need a file, inside another file, and you need a variable to be used in javascript? You didn't even mention javascript in the original post.